# Create Random Raster (Data Management) Generating "No Data" values

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro

I would like to generate a random raster with a cell size of 10 to match an elevation raster's cell size. However attempting to do so with a defined extent creates this incomplete raster with a section of no data:

[image]

If I up the cell size to 20 I get a random raster as expected without sections of "No Data":

[image]

What is causing this behaviour and how can I prevent it while maintining the matching cell size/raster resolution?

I am using ArcGIS Pro 1.4

The "Create Random Raster (Data Management)" tool was used here, using a Uniform distribution with a range of 0 to 10. The extent of the output was set to the extent of the elevation raster using the drop down menu - this defaulted the cell size box to 72, which I manually changed to 10 to match the actual cell size of the elevation raster (taken from the properties dialogue), perhaps this is a clue:

[image]

Comment: Please also add some info about how you created your random raster including a screenshot of your tool parameters if possible

Comment: I have added the screenshot as requested, as well as the relevant details.